# I cant load points in the bing

Tags: javascript, html, bing-maps

I have made the function below. This doesn't work. Not appears points on map.

I give parameters values to function.

```
function getinfo_sendquestionzasobyeduall(anypath, webagent, froms, next, select, radius) {     
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: anypath, //url to file.php
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType:'json',  
        success: function(json)  {                   
            for (var klucz in json) { 
                var wiersz = json[klucz];  
                var zmienna5V1 = wiersz[41]; 
                var zmienna6H1 = wiersz[42];
                //alert('latin:'+zmienna5V1+'  longin:'+zmienna6H1);  
                //show me info about geting sucess -is OK // 
                //next i parametresion function below
                addlocationbingmap(zmienna5V1,zmienna6H1); 
            }
        },
        error: function(error) {
        }
    });
}
```

> in the function i wont add points to map but dont work

```
function addlocationbingmap(geoV1,geoH1)  
{ 
    var navigationBarMode = Microsoft.Maps.NavigationBarMode;
    var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#oringseriesmap',
    {
```

//where your api key

```
        credentials: 'MY API KEY', 
        center: mapCentre, 
        navigationBarMode: navigationBarMode.compact,
        supportedMapTypes: [
            Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road,
            Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.aerial,
            Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.grayscale,
            Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.canvasLight
        ]
    });

    // to value geoV1 and geoH1
    var mylocation = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(parseFloat(geoV1), parseFloat(geoH1));

    // push pin to map
    var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(mylocation, { text: '0', title: '1', subTitle: '', color: '#F00'});

    map.entities.push(pushpin);
}
```

In file *.html :

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol' async defer></script>
```

Comment: Do you have a function declaration (`addlocationbingmap`) inside `for` loop?

Comment: moment I edit code

Comment: Can you please make the layout better? Use proper indentation, also separate explanations about code from the actual code, or put them as comments (using `//`) inside the code.

Comment: I improved the layout, please try do to it yourself next time, it will help us help you.

Comment: I improved the question, but I can't answer it myself.

Comment: Any errors in the console? (Notice you write `ne Microsoft.Maps.Map` instead of `new Microsoft.Maps.Map`). If you can setup a runnable code with codepen or as a snippet in the question it would be very helpful. (You can fake the ajax call with tools like https://beeceptor.com/

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to help you debug this:

- Check the console for errors.
- Try removing "async defer" from the script tag. You haven't added a callback to that script tag reference, and it will load in parallel. This may end up loading the map script after you have called the add location function you created, and thus try to create the map before the SDK has been downloaded into your site.
- Add break points to your code using the browsers developer tools and step through your code to ensure everything it running as expected.
- Make sure you are only creating the map once (your add location function should only be called once). If it is called multiple times, you will end up creating multiple layered maps that hide each other.

Comment: Hi, yes in the function addlocationbingmap()  load a lot off maps and i see only end point map. I should  in the function getinfo_sendquestionzasobyeduall(); declararation all points on one map. Without function addlocationbingmap().